# cp not evaluating dirname properly in find operation

Tags: shell-script, find, quoting

I'm trying to create a script which will find files of a certain filename, copy a  file to that file's location, and then delete the found file.

Ignoring the delete part for now, this is what I have so far:

```
find /path/to/searchdir -name "file.rtf" -exec cp -v "/path/to/filetocopy.rtf" `dirname {}` \;
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to evaluate the dirname properly, as it returns "." for any instances of the file that it finds.

Comment: I think it's because you're trying to use the `{}` macro inside of a subshell, which I don't reckon will work.

Answer (score 3):

`find`'s `-execdir` action seems more appropriate:

```
find /path/to/searchdir -name file.rtf -execdir cp -v /path/to/filetocopy.rtf . \;
```

This will run the `cp` from every directory found containing a file named `file.rtf`, so `.` as seen by `cp` will be the appropriate directory every time `cp` is run.

You can then add `-delete` to delete the file (after checking everything works).

The reason your approach isn't working is that the shell evaluates `dirname {}` before running `find`, and `dirname {}` outputs `.`. So

```
find /path/to/searchdir -name "file.rtf" -exec cp -v "/path/to/filetocopy.rtf" `dirname {}` \;
```

becomes

```
find /path/to/searchdir -name "file.rtf" -exec cp -v "/path/to/filetocopy.rtf" . \;
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about the execdir option which is much more appropriate here. Also didn't know about the order of operations but that makes sense. Thanks for the help!